# Entity Framework cannot connect to Database via Azure Hybrid connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently working on an API, to access data from a SQL Server that is hosted locally. My app is being hosted through an Azure web app. I'm also using Entity Framework 6 in my application to access data. Since my data can't be in the cloud, I created an Azure Hybrid connection to create a relay to my SQL Server.

However, I keep running into this error (see below). I don't understand why this happens. I have checked my firewall rules to make sure that connections from Azure are being permitted. I have also verified that my connection string is correct and that I'm using the right port number. I also verified that remote connections are allowed on the SQL Server.

In case anybody is wondering I'm running SQL Server 2012. Does anyone have a fix for this issue? I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Comment: Are you using a named instance instead of a default instance which listens for requests on static port 1433? I recommend that you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-hybrid-connection-connect-on-premises-sql-server) and check with your environment.

Comment: It would be good if you can share your complete connection string along with the details of your firewall, as you might be needed to allow outbound traffic on certain ports for the hybrid connection to work fine.